# Реализация доступа к трейсеру в NestJs без передачи в параметрах между функциями

Tags: javascript, node.js, логирование, nestjs

В моем приложении NestJs у меня возникла проблема с передачей трейсера (tracer) для логирования запросов. Я обычно сохраняю трейсер в local storage и использую его в различных сервисах в течение запроса. Однако у меня также есть задачи, вызываемые не http-запросом, а, например, Cron задачи, и у них нет доступа к local storage. Каким образом я могу управлять трейсером так, чтобы он был доступен в любом сервисе без необходимости передавать его в параметрах между функциями?